# why running a batch file from jenkins spends more time than running the batch file directly

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am using jenkins to do CI, and in one of my jenkins job's jenkins file
I try to run a batch file which is in a slave agent of jenkins (windows 7 OS), and the batch file is as below:

```
@echo on
"<path1>\eclipse.exe -noSplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data E:\jenkins\build_workspace -cleanBuild <project name>/Debug
exit
```

and in my jenkinsfile, it is like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label "buildserver"} 
        stage {
            script {
                bat 'call <path2>\abc.bat'
            }
        }
}
```

and total build time is about 16-18 minutes.

but when I login in the build server, and try to run the batch file directly in the command line window, the build process time is about 4-5 minutes.

I do not know what is going on ?

Comment: Perhaps you have cached packages which were downloaded previously during the Jenkins job's?

Comment: i do not think so. We tried to clean all local workspace things ,and do the comparsions , also the big difference

Comment: running via jenkins and running directly are not in oder.

Comment: I don't understand why the IDE *Eclipse* is started in a non-graphical execution environment to do a build task. Why do you not run the command line executed by *Eclipse* to do the build task because of *Eclipse* itself cannot do any build at all? I have never seen such an approach before and honestly I would never have the idea to run *Eclipse* by *Jenkins* for a build job. The free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) could be used by you to find out what is going on in the background causing the time diff.

Comment: no, we want to use jenkins to do the building automatically. So the command line is a better choice. Thanks for your help for the moniitor, i will have a try.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been solved. It is the reason of jenkins agent installed as windows service on slave agent of win 7 OS, probably the compatibility between win 7 and jenkins.

refer to [Jenkins job windows batch execution 20 times slower than executing in cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028049/jenkins-job-windows-batch-execution-20-times-slower-than-executing-in-cmd-exe/71670837#71670837).